# rtk Query getting Called twice, because of UseEffect

Tags: react-hooks, rtk-query

I am having a parent component in which there is a button which on click sets a state variable to true/false, based on this stateVariable I am rendering the child component.
Inside the Child component I have a rtkQuery to get a list of Items, and based on the size of the data from the get request, I am changing the state of the variable inside the useEffect.

Issue: When I click the link/button on parent component, the api gets called and the relevant popup is to be opened based on data, which is getting done correctly, but as soon as the popup gets closed, the api in parent component gets called which is fine, but api in the child component also gets called, though child component is not rendered(conditional rendering).

```
//rtk query
getItems: builder.query<IItemsResponse[], string>({
      query: (itemNumber) =>
        `/application/reassign/${itemNumber}/users`,
      providesTags: ["Item"],
      keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
    }),

export const {useGetItemsQuery} =apiSlice;

//rtk-query call in child Component

  const { data, isLoading } = useGetReassignUsersQuery(itemNumber);


//Parent Component Calling Child Component Using

{callModalState && (
        <ItemModal
          setModalState={setModalState}
          itemNumber={itemNumber}
          onCancel={() => {
            setCallModalState(false);
          }}
        onItemSuccess={() => {
            setModalState(false);
            onApplicationSuccess;
          }}
          customToastForError={() => {
            setModalState(false);
            customToastForError;
          }}
        
        />
      )}
    </div>
  
//State in Child Component
const [modalState, setModalState] =
    useState<ModalState>({
      showNoItemModal: false,
      showModal: false,
    });

//useEffect in child Component

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      setModalState({
        ...modalState,
        showModal: true,
        showNoUsersModal: false,
      });
    } else if (data && data.length == 0) {
      setModalState({
        ...ModalState,
        showModal: false,
        showNoItemModal: true,
      });
    }
  }, [data]);
```

The query in child component gets called once before child component is rendered, once after the child component is closed, however I do not want the rtk querty in the child component to be called if i close the popup.